# Will using hadoop 20-append with hbase 90.3 break?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Trying to install hbase, but the word on the street is that if I don't use a hadoop from the 20-append branch, I'll lose data.  This [tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/14/building-an-hadoop-0-20-x-version-for-hbase-0-90-2/) says that it will work with 90.2, but doesn't discuss 90.3.

Is there a newer version of 20-append that I should be using with 90.3, or will the same version of hadoop append work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same version of hadoop with append will work with it.

In fact, HBase 0.90.* will work even without append, but you will run the risk of data loss and corruption if (when) a node fails in an unlucky way.